# Vim print buffer names to stdout on :q

Tags: vim

Let me jump right in.

What I'm trying to do is simply print out the file path of any open buffer when I exit vim.  This is useful because I often open other files in vim buffers with a vim script I wrote that can search through my codebase for a specific function call.

I figure I can set up an autocommand, either for when I open a file or when I leave vim, and use the output from `:ls` to list all currently open buffers.  The problem that I'm having is that I can't get any output to show up in terminal.  I have tried various combinations of `:!echo` in my function, but to no avail.  I have been trying something like the following in my .vimrc

```
function! PrintFileName()
    :!echo "hello"
    :exec "!echo world"
    "... etc
endfunction
au BufRead * call PrintFileName()
```

Both `:!echo foobar` and `:call PrintFileName()` work for me if I do it from the command line.  I also figure I might have to use some form of silent/redraw! so I don't have to hit enter to continue.

Really the main problem here is that I can't see a way to get output to stdout from inside my function and called by an autocommand.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I can't really think of a good way to do this except with rather ugly hacks with wrapper scripts etc... Aside from Vim handling stdout, you also have Vim's terminal drawing code interfering. What you want is to `echo` *after* this code has finished cleaning up...

Comment: The easiest would be to save that buffer list into a file and then `cat` that file once your vim session has terminated. But I must admit, I don't see any useful application. Why leaving vim to do something on a list of buffers?

Comment: @LucHermitte There are often utilities that I might want to run on the files I just edited and having a list right there in the terminal would be extremely nice.  Of course I _could_ do it inside vim, but really I am done editing the files and it is not useful to run there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've found this solution, which works as long as I enter vim from the last line of my terminal.  Otherwise this prints out a line below the current line and will get overwritten when you press enter.  If anyone knows how to fix that let me know, otherwise I will use this.

```
function! PrintBuffers()
    redir => files
    :ls
    redir END
    " Regex to strip out everything from :ls but the buffer filenames
    let files = substitute(files, '^[^"]*"', '', 'g')
    let files = substitute(files, '"[^"]*\n[^"]*"', '\n', 'g')
    let files = substitute(files, '"[^"]*$','','g')
    " This is the magic line
    exe '!echo; echo ' . shellescape(&t_te . files)
endfunction
au VimLeave * call PrintBuffers()
```

*Note - As I'm writing this, I realize that this won't display the right path if you did a `:cd` at some point.  So I guess its pretty fragile, but it does the job.